# How to scompose bitwise value into int array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, int, bit-manipulation, divide

Assuming i have a bitwise value of 66, that is composed by 2 and 64.
Is there a way to scompose this bitwise in javascript so that the result would be an array of integers [2,64] ?

```
//Example 
function transformBW(x) {   //where x = 82;
    ---------
    var result = [2,16,64];  //desired result
    return result;
};

// transformBW(66) = [2,64];
```

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Assumes n is an integer >= 0
function transformBW( n ) {
    var r = [];
    var bv = 1;
    while ( n >= 1 ) {
        if ( n % 2 == 1 ) {
            // Add the bit value (bv) of the LSB left in n
            r.push( bv );
            // Clear that bit
            n -= 1;
        }
        // Shift n down 1 bit, adjusting bit value to the new LSB's value
        bv += bv;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return r;
}
```